Ubuntu 24.04 not booting on MacBook 4.1
I did an in place upgrade from Ubuntu 23.10 to 24.04 on my MacBook 4.1.
If I try to boot the default kernel 6.8.0.35, it won't boot I just get a black screen with a single hyphen in the top left. It will boot 24.04 using the alternative 6.5.0.35 kernel. Is there anything I can do to fix this, or is it best to wait for the next kernel upgrade?
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64
Host: MacBook4,1 1.0
Kernel: 6.5.0-35-generic
DE: GNOME 46.0
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo T8300 (2) @ 2.4GHz
GPU: Intel Mobile GM965/GL960
Memory: 3887MiB

I fixed this issue by installing the latest stable kernel (6.9.3 at this point). This booted fine so its an issue with the 6.8.0.35 kernel on this particular machine.
I followed instructions from here which essentially involved:

Go to Mainline Kernel to find out what is the latest stable kernel.

2)Create a folder, download the correct files for your architecture. They should look something like this...
linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_all.deb
linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
linux-image-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
linux-modules-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
Where VERSION-NUMBER is replaced by whatever is the new version you want to install.
When you have downloaded them all, open the folder with your terminal program, make sure it only contains the downloaded kernel files then use the command sudo dpkg -i *.deb
You then need to use sudo update-grub then sudo reboot and it should boot into the new kernel.

Can you add more details about how you installed the latest stable kernel? It may help future users
